# Excel VBA- VLOOKUP with multiple criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I need a VBA code that searches for a specific Name (first dropdown), Products (second drop-down), then returns the unit price. I can use VLOOKUP to search names and return the unit price but I need to search for names and products and be able to pull the prices quickly. I used Evaluate function but the result is #VALUE!

```
Sub unitPrice()

Set sh4 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Invoice")
Set sh5 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Unit Price")

sh4.Range("H18") = _
sh4.Evaluate("MATCH(" & sh4.Cells(11, 1).Address(False, False) _
& "&" & sh4.Cells(18, 1).Address(False, False) _
& ",'Sh5!B2:B5&sh5!A2:A5,0)")

End Sub
```

[Screenshot of Invoice and Unit Price sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dv67O.jpg)

Comment: `'Sh5!` needs to be `'Unit Price'!`

Comment: No need to go VBA. Say Names are B5:B44, Products at C5:C44, Prices at D5:D44, then put DataValidation in H4 (Name) and DataValidation H5 (product). Now enter in H6 the code: " {=INDEX(D5:D44, -5+MAX((B5:B44=$H$4)*(C5:C44=$H$5)*ROW(C5:C44)))}" and  press ctrl+sht+enter (to enter as array formula). There, job done...

Comment: @rory thanks, I correct it but I think my code is completely wrong because it does not give me a unit price. The match does work but I need to return the unit price from ```vba 'sh5'!C2:C5 ```

Comment: @Apostolos55 I need a VBA code because later maybe I need to change the unit price and copy it back again from the Invoice sheet to the Unit Price sheet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative solution minimising interaction with sheet by matching in memory:

```
Option Explicit
Sub SimpleMatch()
    Dim sh5 As Worksheet, sh4 As Worksheet 'declare vars
    Set sh4 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Invoice") 'set sheet
    Set sh5 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Unit Price") 'set sheet
    
    Dim arr, arr2, LastRowSh4 As Long, LastRowSh5 As Long
    LastRowSh4 = sh4.Cells(sh4.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'count rows from last row
    LastRowSh5 = sh5.Cells(sh5.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'count rows from last row
    
    arr = sh4.Range(sh4.Cells(1, 1), sh4.Cells(LastRowSh4, 8)).Value2 'load invoices to mem
    arr2 = sh5.Range(sh5.Cells(1, 1), sh5.Cells(LastRowSh5, 3)).Value2 'load prices to mem

    Dim j As Long, dict As Object
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary") 'create dictionary lateB
    With dict 'used because I'm to lazy to retype dict everywhere :)
        .CompareMode = 1 'textcompare
        For j = 1 To UBound(arr2) 'add prices to dict
            If Not .Exists(arr2(j, 1) & arr2(j, 2)) Then  'set key if I don't have it yet in dict
                .Add Key:=arr2(j, 1) & arr2(j, 2), Item:=arr2(j, 3)
            End If
        Next j
        
        Dim cust As String
        For j = 1 To UBound(arr)
            If arr(j, 1) = "Bill To:" Then
                cust = arr(j + 1, 1) 'assumes you have only  1 customer in the sheet!
            End If
            If .Exists(arr(j, 1) & cust) Then 'retrieve produc & cust price
                arr(j, 8) = dict(arr(j, 1) & cust) 'add to arr
            End If
        Next j
    End With
    
    With sh4
        .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(UBound(arr), UBound(arr, 2))) = arr 'dump updated array to invoice sheet
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: The solution (Dictionary & Match) you showed me is perfect, and I needed a lot in my project. I do not have much information about it. Do you know a video or a link to introduce me to learn from, thanks

Comment: https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you have two tables (insert > table): tblInvoice and tblUnitPrice. It is much easier to reference them in VBA via `listobject` than without. If you are not using tables you have to adjust the ranges accordingly.

What my code does:  It inserts an INDEX/MATCH-Formula to retrieve the Unitprice for all rows in the table - and then writes the pure values back to the cells.

```vb
Public Sub updateUnitPricesInInvoice()

Dim loInvoice As ListObject
Set loInvoice = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoice").ListObjects("tblInvoice")

With loInvoice.ListColumns("UnitPrice").DataBodyRange
    .Formula2 = "=INDEX(tblUnitPrices[UnitPrice],MATCH(1,(tblUnitPrices[Name]=[@Name])*(tblUnitPrices[Product]=[@Product])))"
    .value = .value
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @lke because I'm not using the table can you tell me how to make it with the range, please?

Comment: It's really a big benefit to learn using tables/listbobjects! Try it! And: As I don't know your sheet, it is pretty hard to adjust the code. At least you have to upload a screenshot of the sheet.

Comment: @lke Thanks for your recommendation definitely I'll learn about tables/listbobjects. Because I need it for many projects. Also, I upload a screenshot of the Invoice and Unit Price sheet.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution without tables/listobjects:

Assumption: you have added names for the following cells on invoice sheet

- A11: customer
- A17: labelDescription
- H17: labelUnitPrice
- H28: labelTotalAmount

In the first step we retrieve the range between the two labels "UnitPrice" and "TotalAmount" - that's where the formula goes.

Then the formula is written to that range - using again INDEX/MATCH.
In case there is not description nothing is displayed (there ISERROR)

And again: after calculation formulas are replaced by their values

```vb
Option Explicit

Public Sub updateUnitPricesInInvoice()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Invoice")

Dim rgUnitPrices As Range
Set rgUnitPrices = getRangeBetweenTwoLabels(ws, "labelUnitPrice", "labelTotalAmount")


With rgUnitPrices
    'Excel 365
    '.Formula2 = "=IFERROR(INDEX(UnitPrice!C:C,MATCH(1,(UnitPrice!A:A=Invoice!" & ws.Range("labelDescription").Offset(1).Address(False, True) & ")*(UnitPrice!B:B=customer),0)),"""")"

    'other Excel versions
    With rgUnitPrices
        .Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX(UnitPrice!C:C,MATCH(1,(UnitPrice!A:A=Invoice!$A" & rgUnitPrices.Rows(1).Row & ")*(UnitPrice!B:B=customer),0)),"""")"
        .FormulaArray = .FormulaR1C1
    End With
    .Value = .Value
End With

End Sub


Private Function getRangeBetweenTwoLabels(ws As Worksheet, _
    label1 As String, label2 As String)
    
Dim cStart As Range: Set cStart = ws.Range(label1).Offset(1)
Dim cEnd As Range: Set cEnd = ws.Range(label2).Offset(-1)

Set getRangeBetweenTwoLabels = ws.Range(cStart, cEnd)

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, but when I run it, it give an "error runtime error 438 object doesn't support this property or method" for .Formula2

Comment: Ahh - then you don't have Excel 365 - I added an alternative to the code above

Comment: And I received new error "run-time error '1004' unable to set formulaarray property of the range class"

Comment: Which version of Excel do you have?

Comment: I updated the code - on my machine it works - let's see if on yours as well ...